# How to add callback: cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to add call back to my `googleApiClient` with `addConnectionCallbacks`

```
mPlusClient  = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

but I am getting this error:

`Error:(85, 81) error: incompatible types: PlusBaseActivity cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks`

I am gotten this code from an online tutorial but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have any experience with what you are doing, but might it be the case that the `PlusBaseActivity` class has to implement `ConnectionCallbacks` in order to 'be' a callback? Like:

```
public class PlusBaseActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks{
// add ConnectionCallBack methods
}
```

Comment: If you want to learn more about inheritance, read this great [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

Answer (score 0):

implements methods

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
   Log.i("LOG", "Conectado ao Google Play Services!");
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
   Log.i("LOG", "Conexão Interrompida");
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
   Log.i("LOG", "Erro ao conectar: " + connectionResult);
}
```